# Why comment reply auto-completion feature (@) sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: support, comment-replies, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Say, we've got an answer with some comments under it.
Sometimes when I want to reply to one of the comments, I can easily refer to the comment author printing @ and starting to enter the author's name, that is autocompleted for me.
But sometimes (if only one person gave comments or not...) I'm not suggested with any variant.
Why is it so? On what terms does it depend?

Comment: Related: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won’t autocomplete if the person you are answering is the owner of the post.  Indeed, it will remove that if you try, after you submit the comment.

The reason for this behavior is that the owner of the post will always be notified anyway.  Explicit notification would just waste space.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I see now how it works

Comment: [It's confusing, though.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27543/my-student-told-me-his-mother-has-cancer-what-do-i-do#comment58593_27545)

Comment: Oh no, not `SE`'s precious space!  **How about the loss of meaning/comprehensibility that ensues by denying us use of the noun/directive in our sentence?**  Let US decide when we want to address the OP, thanks.  It's like Nazi Germany around here. Oh, this is for you, @tchrist, lol.